# Track the elements rendered on Scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

Thanks for your time.

I'm developing a page which has a top **Calendar component**( which show a week) and below that, a **Scroll component** which shows information for each one of the days of the week.

This is my page so far:
[image: Web]

The problem here is that I need to know what day the scroll is showing to mark it at the calendar, like this example where the user is at day 3 and day 3 is marked at the calendar:
[image: how it should look]
I have seen scroll tracking questions where the solutions are linked to ScrollY and ScrollX position, but in this case I need some info of the DOM element, like id or something, and I don't know if it's possible.

I also have tried onScroll method of the react infinite scroll, but it returns the whole document.

This is the code:

[image: Code]

And the console print:
[image: console print]
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you add your code please?

Comment: Sure @OrAssayag!.

Comment: what is the library do u use ?

Comment: I'm using React and react-infinite-scroll-component @ridoansaleh

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `useRef()` hook to reference the parent container within the `onScroll` function passed to the `InfiniteScroll` component. In that function you could use the parent reference to calculate which element is currently visible (closest to the middle of visible container). Then, pass item's date to a higher order component which is also shared with the calendar component.

Note: you would need to set the `scrollableTarget` property of the `InfiniteScroll` (because we want our parent element to be responsible for
scrollbars).

```js
function InfiniteScrollContainer({ setFocusedItem }) {
  const container = useRef();

  function handleScroll() {
    // Calculate which item is currently in the middle of the container
    const containerMiddle = container.current.scrollTop + container.current.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2;
    const infiniteScrollItems = container.current.children[0].children;
    let index = 0;
    let itemFound = false;
    const itemNo = infiniteScrollItems.length;
    while (!itemFound && index < itemNo) {
      const item = infiniteScrollItems[i];
      const itemTopOffset = item.offsetTop;
      const itemBottomOffset = item.getBoundingClientRect().height + itemTopOffset;
      if (itemTopOffset < containerMiddle && itemBottomOffset > containerMiddle) {
        setFocusedItem(item);
        itemFound = true;
      }
      index += 1;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleScroll();
  }, [])

  /* ... */

  return (
    <div ref={container} id="container-id">
      <InfiniteScroll
        <!-- ... -->
        scrollableTarget={"container-id"}
        onScroll={handleScroll}
      >
        <!-- ... -->
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  );
}
```